# How many cookie should I create for multiple devices?

Tags: php, algorithm, security, cookies

I'm trying to create a cookie to keep my website's users logged. I let the person log in from multiple devices. Well can I create one identical cookie for all user's devices? Or should I store multiple different cookies for different devices *(and why)*?

---

Actually I don't see any problem with having one common cookie for an specific user on multiple devices. Also that cookie isn't changeable. That will be always fixed until the user changes his password. I create that cookie like this:

```
md5($password.$user_id.$username);
```

That cookie is based on the password because I want to log-out him when he changes his password, otherwise he will be logged into all devices that he already logged.

Am I doing that right correct?

Comment: well as cookies are stored on the clinets machine, how would you use one only?

Comment: @Dagon What? yes they are stored on the client side .. so?

Comment: well if they are on multiple devices each devise will need a cookie.

Comment: @Dagon Yes each device needs a cookie, I mean all cookies *(on different devices)* are identical *(for an specific user)*. Is that wrong?

Comment: ok, i wasn't clear on what you meant by just one cookie- so yes each needs one and i see no benefit in them not being identical. Your site should not really care the source of any transaction, just the id of the user. also dont use md5 its basically broken. and what ever hash i would not put the password in a cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cryptographic hash algorithm MD5 has already begun to be broken, mainly in regards to its collision resistance property, as well as preimage resistance slightly. See [the Wikipedia article, in the security section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security).

Therefore I would not use MD5 for anything slightly security related. A similar story with SHA-1 in that it has began to be broken, so I would use [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) if you do indeed need a hashing algorithm.

The problem with your approach is that you cannot revoke the token from individual devices easily. Also having password as input to your algorithm could make it vulnerable to a hash cracking attack, should the other values be known. Don't rely on your method being secret either, [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) states "A cryptosystem should be secure even if everything about the system, except the key, is public knowledge.".

Also another problem with your approach is that your hashing algorithm needs plaintext access to the password, which could suggest you are storing passwords insecurely. In short [ensure you are using bcrypt for password storage](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6415/8340). Of course, you may be creating the cookie and storing a server-side version of it at a point where the user enters their password, however given that you want to invalidate cookies automatically upon password change makes me think not.

The most secure way to manage devices with tokens is to generate a 128-bit random token per device, and store this hashed with SHA-2 in your database. Ensure a CSPRNG is used to generate the token.

Therefore:

```
    Cookie value: 128-bit token
    Database value: SHA-2(128-bit token)
```

Note that salts are not required for values of such bit strength. Then when a user changes their password, you simply delete all server-side tokens for the user. Additionally, you will be able to allow the user to revoke tokens for different devices individually without any password change required.

The reason for hashing on the server-side is to mitigate any session hijacking should an attacker gain access to your sessions table.

Comment: Thank you .. upvote ...! Just you said *" to revoke tokens for different devices individually"* .. that means each device has its own cookie. So should I store multiple cookies *(in multiple devices)* for **one** user?

Comment: Yes, why not have a different cookie per device? So a one-to-many relationship between user and device token.

Comment: Ok you tell me why not have an identical cookie for all devices? Why the cookie cannot be the same into all user's devices? Look, [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/14749dca7640e3b9e318cb7729e65f8c) is my table strucute, How can I store multiple cookies for one user? I just have one column for cookie, if I update for new device, previous device will be log out.

Comment: I've answered why in my answer above. You need a separate table for your devices. The technical implementation is a separate question - please post as a new question, and maybe link back to this one for context.

Comment: @bill Well you can detect if your cookie is hijacked should you need to in future. If the same token is being used in two different locations simultaneously you can mitigate by implementing rolling token values. If you share the token across devices you won't be able to do that. Also it's possible to revoke individual device access, useful if an account is logged into numerous times, you don't have to log them all out. It very much depends on the application how useful this is but I always aim to make my answers as widely useful as possible.

Comment: Ok, I've followed your idea and created a separated table for cookies. I mean currently I create different cookies for different devices. But I faced with a huge problem. Please if you have some free time, take a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085782/how-can-i-detect-redundant-rows-in-the-table

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing that right correct?

Unfortunately no.

By creating  cookies with this design: `md5($password.$user_id.$username)`,  you are implementing them in their *most naive approach*. A basic  rule of thumb is to never store user's credentials within a cookie. This is valid for whatever powerful the hashing algorithm you use may be. And for the MD5 algorithm you are using, it is not that strong ([***Transcript Collision Attacks: Breaking Authentication in TLS, IKE, and SSH***](http://www.mitls.org/downloads/transcript-collisions.pdf))

> Or should I store multiple different cookies for different devices
>   (and why)?

You do not have to. Useless. And as a good security principle, never add functionality (code) to your software if you do not need it otherwise you may enhance the [**attack surface**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Attack_Surface_Analysis_Cheat_Sheet).