# Force Public-Key-Pins max-age to renew the Pins

Tags: ssl-certificate, public-key

Regularly you set a max-age to Public-Key-Pins (HPKP) to be valid for 1 or 2 years in seconds. What about if you change before the SSL run out your SSL Certificate and Visitors still have the Public-Key-Pin of the old Certificate?

It should be done without that the Visitor has to do with the Browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Important distinction**: Public key pinning pins the public key, not the certificate. The certificate *contains* the public key, but also contains a signature of the public key (and associated metadata) from a certificate authority.

How I use HPKP:

1. Generate 3 key pairs.
2. Upload one to the server, use for HTTPS.
3. Include the SHA256 hash of all three public keys in the HPKP header.

That gives me two backups. I keep them both on encrypted storage; one is kept on my person, the other in a safe.

Other people pin to intermediate certificates from multiple certificate authorities.

Also, a max-age of two months is adequate. Attackers also have certificate transparency (and the SSL Observatory for users with the HTTPS Everywhere extension) to contend with.

Comment: Key-Pairs: CSR+PrivateKey without Certificates? I am new to this. Sorry for stupid questions.

Comment: Key-Pair: a private key and corresponding public key.

Comment: You are the author of this [this article](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/secure-authentication-php-with-long-term-persistence#title.2), right? Well I have a question about it. How `expires` column works? My similar question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085782/how-can-i-detect-redundant-rows-in-the-table), Please write an answer for me.