# How can I detect user's device?

Tags: php, algorithm, security, cookies

I'm trying to create a system which keeps the user logged in *(something like remember me checked)*. Ok I have a table like this:

```
// cookies
+---------+-------------------------+------------------+------------+------------+
|   id    |         email           |     cookie       | date_time  |   device   |
+---------+-------------------------+------------------+------------+------------+
| int(11) |      varchar(50)        |   varchar(128)   |  int(11)   |            |
+---------+-------------------------+------------------+------------+------------+
| 1       | jack_2009@gmail.com     | ojer0f934mf2...  | 1467204523 |            |
| 2       | peter.zm@yahoo.com      | ko4398f43043...  | 1467205521 |            |
| 3       | matrix_john23@gmail.com | 34fjkg3j438t...  | 1467205601 |            |
| 4       | peter.zm@yahoo.com      | 0243hfd348i4...  | 1467206039 |            |
+---------+-------------------------+------------------+------------+------------+
```

As you see, this user `peter.zm@yahoo.com` have logged in by two different devices:

```
| 2       | peter.zm@yahoo.com      | ko4398f43043...  | 1467205521 |            |
| 4       | peter.zm@yahoo.com      | 0243hfd348i4...  | 1467206039 |            |
```

So `email` column isn't unique and each device has its own row.

**My question:** How can I fill `device` column?

---

Why do I need to determine devices? Because when an user removes his browser's cookies, then my website identifies him as a new user and creates a new row for him into table above. So after a while, there will be some redundant rows in the table.

For example: Imagine `peter` has just two devices *(laptop, phone)*. And he have two rows into table above. Ok, he removes his browser's cookies and logs in. What happens? My website creates a new row into table above. Now `peter` has 3 rows into table above *(while he has just two devices)*. So surely one of those three rows is redundant. That's why I need to detect devices to remove redundant rows.

Comment: This look like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag. It's fine that you want to store it in MySQL, and maybe that explanation may help visualize the problem, but in itself the question (how to get some unique device identification) is not related to MySQL.

Comment: A question I'd like to ask in return is: Do you even need two rows? You can [set the session_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) in PHP, so you could recycle the same cookie value, get the same session information and just continue with the settings he set before on the other device. But that's just a suggestion, and I don't know if that would work for you (which is where @FirstOne's XY problem comes in).

Comment: Nothing in that table tells me Peter logged in on two different devices. Couldn't he have logged in from the same device but multiple browsers, or even incognito mode? Also unclear why the number of devices matter or how this data is being used..

Comment: @chris85 You are right .. so what's the standard approach to manage this? Actually the whole of my question is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38085782/how-can-i-detect-redundant-rows-in-the-table)

Comment: @GolezTrol That's a XY problem? Ok fine, what's the normal way to do that?

Comment: Why do you need the logged in state in the DB? Just check if the `SESSION` is active when the user visits your page.

Comment: @chris85 What? I need to store the value of the cookie into database to compare it with user's cookie. Do you know what's "remember me option"? I want user just log in once .. not every time.

Comment: Use this http://hgoebl.github.io/mobile-detect.js/ to detect device and store the device info to the table

Comment: when next time when submitting to db userinfo check for the username and device already exist

Comment: if yes then dont insert else insert to db.. and create a cookie.. and also check for cookie with the same info exists else create a cookie

Comment: @NadeemmnnMohd That's a javascript library .. So it won't work for the user who has disabled JS on his browser.

Comment: thats a rare case and without js how do u validate ?

Comment: if u are using dotnet or java you should have handlers which detects the browser info as well

Comment: @NadeemmnnMohd I don't know .. actually that's the question. I think I don't need to store the device at all *(based on other comments)*

Comment: @GolezTrol Your suggestion seems good to me .. may you please write an answer about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about with the [User Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string from their last interaction with your application?

As an additional defence-in-depth security measure, you could also validate that the user agent matches their previously used one for this device in order to mitigate session hijacking. Be aware that any browser or OS upgrades will invalidate the "remember-me" on that device though.

As a side note, you are better off keying on a unique ID rather than email address because that way it is much easier to update a user's email should you need to in future.

Comment: Ok thank you .. upvote. Just about your *a side note*, I have to say user doesn't enter his id, he enters his email. So I have to use user's email for validating. Or fetch user's id before validating *(which needs one more query)*.

Comment: The second one, or you can make your query join both tables to go from ID --> email.

Answer (score 0):

Use the web authn api or the credentials api